# Keep SQL Queries Outside From Application

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, spring-boot, mssql-jdbc

I want to execute SQL query via from request parameters in Spring Boot application. For Example:

*if request param = X -> execute "select * from Customer"

if request param = Y -> execute "select * from Company"*

But I don't want keep sql queries in Java code. I keep them another place so if new parameter add don't need deploy Sprint Boot application. Is there any idea for solving this problem?

Comment: What you want to do doesn't fully make sense.  The queries return a set of columns -- and the two queries you specify probably have very different return sets.  The application needs to deal with them, so the application should know what query is running.

Comment: you should be able to save them each in an sql file and then execute the sql file in totality

Comment: This is a pretty weird design, but... you *could* store the queries themselves in the database, in a table like `Queries(param char primary key, queryText varchar(max))`.